# Displaying Tiff files in SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, tiff

I have a requirement to be be able to embed scanned tiff images into some SSRS reports.

When I design a report in VS2005 and add an image control the tiff image displays perfectly however when I build it. I get the warning :

`Warning    2   [rsInvalidMIMEType] The value of the MIMEType property for the image ‘image1’ is “image/tiff”, which is not a valid MIMEType.   c:\SSRSStuff\TestReport.rdl 0   0`

and instead of an image I get the little red x.

Has anybody overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're delivering the image file via IIS, use an ASP.NET page to change image formats and mime type to something that you *can* use.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
Response.Clear();
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tifFilepath))
  bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Didn't complile for me. This does though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126584/displaying-tiff-files-in-ssrs-reports#132873 S

Comment: It was a sketch only, not clipped from real code. May I suggest you use PNG rather than JPEG unless you are processing photographic images? Tiff is a non-loss format; this is why I selected another non-loss format.

Comment: In the code from which the idea came I compose a tile of a specified size from smaller aerial photo tiles. Then I draw annotations on it and deliver the finished image. The code is far too involve to clearly illustrate the principle.

Comment: I got some weird gdi error with png. Jpeg will suit for this task.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. That's a bug in conversion to a quantised palette, it doesn't get initialised correctly. As I recall you can dodge this by converting to BMP and then to PNG.

Answer (score 2):

I have been goggling fora solution on how to display a TIFF image in a SSRS report but I couldn't find any and since SSRS doesn's support TIFF, I thought converting the TIFF to one of the suppported format will do the trick. And it did. I don't know if there are similar implementation like this out there, but I am just posting so others could benefit as well. 
Note this only applies if you have a TIFF image saved on database.

```
Public Shared Function ToImage(ByVal imageBytes As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes)
    Dim os As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)

    img.Save(os, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Return os.ToArray()
End Function
```

Here’s how you can use the code:
   1. In the Report Properties, Select Refereneces, click add and browse System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0 
   2. Select the Code Property, Copy paste the function above 
   3. Click Ok 
   4. Drop an Image control from the toolbox 
      4.1. Right-Click the image and select Image Properties 
      4.2. Set the Image Source to Database 
      4.3. In the Use this field, Click expression and paste the code below 
           =Code.ToImage(Fields!FormImage.Value)
      4.4. Set the appropriate Mime to Jpeg

Regards,
Fulbert

Comment: I know this is old but my company is still using SSRS 2005 reports and a previous developer had created a dependency upon the .Net framework in SQL Server to convert our TIFF images to bitmaps for display on a report.  We've been struggling trying to figure out a way to eliminate this dependency as we move forward with a new version of SQL Server.  Fulbert's answer solved the problem perfectly!!  I can't thank you enough for sharing this!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19931/peter-wone) your code didn't compile but the idea was sound.

Here is my attempt that works for me.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Response.Clear();        
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tifFileLocation);
    bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    Response.End();

}
```